# Catch print output in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
print('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
```

This is printing a random color code to the screen. I would like to be able to assign the printed result (eg. #8498C3) to a string so I will have `print_str = "#8498C3"`.
 Now I know that it might be another way of assigning this value (#8498C3) to print_str (witch I don't know btw) but I want to specifically have the **printed output** to that string (print_str).

Another example might be `list_print = ["How", 2 , "catch" , "a" , "print" , "in" , Python , "3.4"]`. Printing this would output: `['How', 2, 'catch', 'a', 'print', 'in', 'Python', 3.4]`. I should have this result `print_str = "['How', 2, 'catch', 'a', 'print', 'in', 'Python', 3.4]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `print` to a file object. If you want to save it to a string... Just save it to a variable:

```
a = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())
```

Comment: What about the list print, how can I get the same format so I can assign it to a string variable?

Comment: @faceoff By casting it to a string value: `my_string = str(list_print)`

Comment: Got it now! My whole question sounds dumb now but I'm new to python. Thank you!